# How has uploadify managed to create a 500 rather than a 404 for an unmapped URL?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

It would appear someone is attempting to breach my Spring Boot web app.

According to my ErrorController implementation, the path responsible for the error shown below was **/uploadify/uploadify.php**. There is no mapping for this path: visiting it results in a 404.

I'm at a loss to understand how a request to this url could have invoked `FrameworkServlet.doPost()`, resulting in the following (pared-down) stack trace:

`Forwarding to error page from request [/uploadify/uploadify.php] due to exception [Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly]
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:112) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:86) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:79) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1100) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]`

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: HTTP status 500 means there is an internal server error. That error is before Spring MVC knows that there is no mapping for `/uploadify/uploadify.php`. The error message shows the reason: *stream ended unexpectedly*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dur. So, had the stream not ended prematurely, the ultimate result would have been a 405 Post not supported?

Comment: 405 or 404, if there is no controller at all.